# I am receiving an error message "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'is_component_type'"

Tags: optimization, pyomo

Doing optimization homework for class, getting a strange error

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as  pd
from io import StringIO
from scipy.stats import norm

from pylab import *
from pyomo.environ import *

cost = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Ben/anaconda3/INFO4590PyomoData.xlsx",sheet_name="SOECost", index_col=0)

shift = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Ben/anaconda3/INFO4590PyomoData.xlsx",sheet_name="SOEShifts", index_col=0)

consts = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Ben/anaconda3/INFO4590PyomoData.xlsx",sheet_name="SOECons", index_col=0)

model=ConcreteModel()

#Dv's

S = shift.keys()
L = cost.index

model.span=Var(S, domain=NonNegativeIntegers)
model.e=Var(S, domain=NonNegativeIntegers)

#ObjFct
model.cost = Objective(expr=sum(model.span[s]*1.1+model.e[s] for s in S), sense = minimize)

#Constraints
model.cons=ConstraintList()

H = consts.index

#make a spanish constraint first
for h in H:
    model.cons.add(sum([model.span[s]*shift.loc[h,s] for s in S]) >= consts.loc[h,'Spanish'])
    
for h in H:
    model.cons.add(sum([(model.span[s]+model.e[s])*shift.loc[h,s] for s in S]) >= consts.loc[h,'Total'])
```

Tried all sorts of things

Comment: Two things:  First, format your code as code.  Just select the code segment and format hit the code format button (or ctrl-k).  Indicate which line is causing the error.  You will likely get better help if your question is clearly written, showing the exact error + line and is reproducible.